# nodejs global variables not working as expected

Tags: node.js

I am working on my first node module and I am struggling a little bit with variables in my functions. The first console log gives me my data, but the second console log is giving me undefined.

```
module.exports = {
  getClient: function() {
    var options_auth={user: username, password: password};

    return new Client(options_auth);
  },

  getTestCaseById: function(client, args, testCaseId) {
    var restResponse;
    url = baseurl + "testcase/" +testCaseId;

    client.get(baseurl + "testcase/" +testCaseId, args, function(data, response) {
        restResponse = data;
        console.log(data);
    });

    console.log(restResponse);
  }
};
```

Thoughts on what I am doing wrong with that restResponse variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the `.get` call is async. The console.log after the `client.get` function is ran while that data call is still in progress. The one inside that call is ran once the call is complete - called a *callback* function.

Do all of your work within the callback to use the returned data, or pass the returned data to another function.

To return the data:

```
getTestCaseById: function(client, args, testCaseId, callback) {
    var restResponse;
    url = baseurl + "testcase/" +testCaseId;

    client.get(baseurl + "testcase/" +testCaseId, args, function(data, response) {
        restResponse = data;
        callback(data)
    });
}
```

Then pass a callback in:

```
getTestCaseById(client, args, testCaseId, function(response) {
    console.log(response); //your returned data
});
```